# How to append dynamic value to string for comparison?

Tags: jquery

I have a data coming through restAPI as follows

```
{
    "count": 2,
        "status1": "OK",
        "graphCode1": "B",
        "graphData1": [{
        "key": "Sports",
            "values": [{
            "label": "Cricket",
                "value": 7
        }, "label": "Football", "value": 4
        }]
    }],
    "status2": "OK",
    "graphCode2": "L",
    "graphData2": [{
        "key": "Age",
        "values": [{
            "x": 0,
            "y": "24"
        }, {
            "x": 1,
            "y": "23"
        }, {
            "x": 2,
            "y": "23"
        }, {
            "x": 3,
            "y": "27"
        }, {
            "x": 4,
            "y": "21"
        }, {
            "x": 5,
            "y": "27"
        }, {
            "x": 6,
            "y": "25"
        }, {
            "x": 7,
            "y": "23"
        }, {
            "x": 8,
            "y": "24"
        }, {
            "x": 9,
            "y": "23"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I an trying to generate string for compare with response

jQuery

```
$.post("<?php echo BASE_URL . php/processing/showGraphsOnUserDashboard.php'; ?>", {}, function(data) {
    // processing for count = 1;

    } else if (data.count === 2) {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            var place = '#graph' + i + ' svg';
            console.log(place);
            console.log(data.status + i);        
            if (data.status+i === "OK") {
                // processing
            }
```

when i try to console it is shows me the error " NaN". Means it is not getting the string as status1 subsequently status2.

How to do that???

Comment: actually status is the key likewise in the json data you can see. if count is 1 then its status1 & if count is 2 the it is status1 & status2...

Comment: Data is invalid, there's a `{` missing before `"label": "Football"`

Comment: Just use data["status"+i] instead of data.status+i

Comment: well i have put my data which is coming from jsonResponse someone foolish have edited this data recently

Comment: @Shaggie, Can you please accept my answer, I have posted it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `data["status"+i]` instead of data.status+i

So for `i = 2` it would resolve to `data["status2"]`

Final code:

```
  console.log(data["status" + i]);        
            if (data["status" + i] === "OK") {
                // processing
            }
```

That's It..

Happy Coding :)